# Why is it a bad idea to exit an Android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

I just read that it is a bad idea to have an exit button on the surface of an Android application.  Why is it a bad idea?  Thanks stack overflow

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238).

Comment: just search exiting android application in search on SO and you will get tons of answers...

Comment: I guess there are many reasons, but a primary one is - users are USED to EXIT WITH BACK BUTTON. Exiting with an in-app button is ANNOYING, many people HATE it when you click back and the app doesn't exit. I do, for example...